# How to draw graphics in iphone gesture?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gesture

I have a question to draw a line or circle indicator after user has pan gesture (i.e. user touches and drags their finger) on iPhone. However, UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() always returns nil, does anyone know how to implement this on iPhone?

Thanks,
clu

```
@interface MyView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
CGPoint location;
PanIndicator *panIndicator;
}

@implementation MyView 
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
        [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panGesture setDelegate:self];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
        [panGesture release];

        panIndicator = [[PanIndicator alloc] init];
        [self addSubview:panIndicator];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gR {
    if ([gR state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        location = [gR locationInView:self];
    } else if ([gR state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //  The following code in this block is useless due to context = nil
//      CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
//      CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 60.0, 60.0));
//      CGContextStrokePath(context);
    } else if ([gR state]==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint location2 = [gR locationInView:self];
        panIndicator.frame = self.bounds;
        panIndicator.startPoint = location;
        panIndicator.endPoint = location2;
//      [panIndicator setNeedsDisplay];    //I don't know why PanIncicator:drawRect doesn't get called
        [panIndicator drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)]; //CGRectMake is useless
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of the finger in your application's data part. Call `[myCanvasView setNeedsDisplay]` in `-(void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gR` and in myCanvasView `-drawInRect:(CGRect)rect` method draw this track.

Something like this:

```
- (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gR 
{
    [myData addPoint:[gR locationInView:gR.view]];
    [myCanvasView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self drawLinesFromData:myData];
}
```

A draft for PanIndicator:

```
@interface PanIndicator : UIView {}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint startPoint;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint endPoint;
@end

@implementation PanIndicator
@synthesize startPoint = startPoint_;
@synthesize endPoint = endPoint_;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect 
{
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    UIBezierPath *pathToDraw = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [pathToDraw moveToPoint:self.startPoint];
    [pathToDraw addLineToPoint:self.endPoint];
    [pathToDraw stroke]
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did currently. But it's not straight forward if I just want to have a circle indicator to show where users finger are? Is it possible to show an indicator at 'location2' directly? Or I have to do it at drawRect:?

Comment: Sure, make a view for indicator (maybe UIImageView will be enough). And move this views position according to gesture coordinates. Show it when gesture starts and hide when it ends.

Comment: Zapko, thanks for the hint. It's good for the circle indicator. But how to cooperate with line indicator during pan gesture? Currently I have 3 indicators, the start point circle, the pan gesture line, and the end point circle. It looks like it's complicated to show the UI smoothly. One problem is the repaint issue.

Comment: Ok, to make a pan indicator you can subclass UIView. It should have start point, end point, and `drawRect` method to draw a line from one point to another. And don't forget to disable its user interactions.

Comment: Is there any sample code for reference for such pan indicator? I try to do it from scratch, but I have no idea how to get started.

Comment: Zapko, thanks for your code snippet. I tried, but the red pan indicator can not show. The parent view is UIView, so I use addSubView: to add PanIndicator, is it correct? The drawRect: in PanIndicator has been get called actually, but I have no idea why it does not show up.

Comment: @clu: what frame do you set to it? don't forget that pan indicator will draw in itself coordinate system while you set start & end points in its superviews coordinate system

Comment: Zapko: I have updated my code. And it will use the PanIndicator from your post. Was it caused by incorrect coordinate system? I suppose to use whole screen when drawing.

Comment: @clu: I believe you should set `panIndicator.frame = viewInWichGestureRecognizerWorks.bounds`

Comment: But I still don't see the red line output after adding panIndicator.frame = self.bounds; as you can see in the code. I also try to move it in init(), but the whole screen will be in black. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should move it to init. Black screen is because we haven't set `panIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` and return `[panIndicator setNeedDisplay]` you should never call drawRect directly it is a bad style, even for debugging. 1) check wether you panAction method is called at all 2) try to set start and end points of indicator at init and check wether it will be visible

Answer (score 0):

I did this with a custom gesture. When the gesture sets the gesture state (from touches began, moved or ended) the gestures action callback occurs back in the view, and the view calls "setNeedsDisplayInRect" and then the drawing occurs from `drawRect`.

The catch with your implementation is that you do not get to set the graphics context from within the gesture's tracking methods. When a view is flagged as needing redraw (via 'setNeedsDisplay') this is done for you.

The reason for this is so that the view's contents can be cached in a layer, which is really important for optimising animations and compositing. So if you need to draw in a view, keep the rest of the interface in sync with your changes by calling `setNeedsDisplay` and doing the drawing from your `drawRect` method.