# Points Versus Pixels ios 

Tags: iphone, ipad, pixel, cgpoint

I have  uiview , that I zoom in and out in it

I associate it with pinchRecognizerMeasure   using

```
pinchRecognizerMeasure = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(MeasureAndDraw:)];
[pinchRecognizerMeasure setDelegate:self];
[DrawLine addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizerMeasure];
[pinchRecognizerMeasure release];
```

the code of MeasureAndDraw

```
    // get position of touches, for example:
    NSUInteger num_touches = [pinchRecognizerMeasure numberOfTouches];

    // save locations to some instance variables, like `CGPoint location1, location2;`
    if (num_touches >= 1) {

        DrawLine.startPoint = [pinchRecognizerMeasure locationOfTouch:0 inView:DrawLine];
    }
    if (num_touches >= 2) {

        DrawLine.endPoint = [pinchRecognizerMeasure locationOfTouch:1 inView:DrawLine];
    }
```

startPoint , endPoint are CGPoint , I want to get the equivalent pixel to it

what shall I do is it correct to do something like

startPoint.X * DrawLine.contentScaleFactor  to get the pixl x coordinate or what shall I do

I read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html , but get  confused

any suggestion

Comment: Why do you think you need pixels? Most of the time, it is points what you need.

Comment: Have a look at his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436990/draw-line-with-gesture) He's looking to be able to get a measurement of line length by translating the pixel length to real length using a scale that he has in pixels. But points are not necessarily pixels in iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `contentScaleFactor` property of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) to translate between points and pixels on the device if you really need to.