# i want to draw with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, uipangesturerecognizer

i want to draw the paths an user draws in the screen using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

I am using the following functions but without any results.

Please let me know where am i doing wrong.

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{

     [[UIColor greenColor]set];
     CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);


     if (sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         CGContextMoveToPoint(context, [sender locationInView:self.view].x, [sender locationInView:self.view].y);
         NSLog(@"touch phase began");
     }

     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, [sender locationInView:self.view].x, [sender locationInView:self.view].y);

     if (sender.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
         CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [draw-line-with-gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436990/draw-line-with-gesture) link where drawing is done with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: thanks for the response.I have look into it but what happens is i cannot able to retain the previous lines. Meaning to say is like i am not getting the whole line from starting of pan gesture to its ending point. I am only able to get line for recent point to current point..This is not what i wanted..how to store the previous lines??every time i draw new lines in the drawRect old line got disappeared..